# Line segment in regular hexagon

Tags: geometry

The regular hexagon ABCDEF has perimeter 84 cm . How long is AD ?
Clockwise, the letters are in the following sequence: EDCBAF.

Answer (score 1):

The hexagon is split into 2 trapeziums if you draw AD.

Since you know it's perimeter, you can work out its side lengths. You can use this (with Pythagorus) to calculate the area of one of the 6 equilateral triangles a regular hexagon can be split into, and hence the area of the hexagon.

Then try creating an equation using AD to find the area of the 2 trapeziums. Now you have an equation using the this, and the above, which you can solve.

Comment: Considering the fact this is a SweSAT question, I find your answer a little bit too complicated maybe for this questions but I thank you for sharing your views

Comment: Complicated? I think it is probably the easiest way to go about doing the question, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes complicated, since I found a much easier way to find the answer. Since the total sum of angles is 720 then we know that 720/6 = 120 degrees for one angle. and then we draw lines to ABCDEF from the center. We get 6 triangles and we know that 120/2 = 60 so the triangles are equilterals. And we know that 84/6 = 14 cm so all sides of triangles has to be 14 cm and 14 + 14 = 28cm. / Greetings from Moscow, Russia

Comment: I am mistaken then for not seeing that simpler solution.

Comment: I forgive you, always be humble in mathematics and never act arrogant.